# Web sites on IIS 7.5 for local network only

Tags: iis-7.5

I have IIS 7.5 running on my Win7 x64 dev machine.

For testing purposes I have set up a site called "site1.com" on it. I can access it as "http://site1.com" on my local machine.

However, there are a few other machines on my local network, some Win7 but some MACs as well. I want all of them to be able to access the site in their browser with "http://site1.com".

I know I can do that by changing the host files on all of them.
However, I am planning on adding more sites and changing host files becomes cumbersome after a while, especially on the macs.

Is there another way to go about it without having to change anything on the local machines (except for the IIS host machine)?

Note: I don't want the local sites to be accessible from outside the local network, only from within it.

Comment: IIS can at time be cumbersome.  I also have a IIS server running on my network, but left it in favour of Apache webserver.  Much easier to configure.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your network is set up you should be able to set up an internal DNS server and point all the machines on your network to it. Then you can add entries for the names you want to use locally, and have the DNS server resolve internet wide names by talking to your current DNS server. Set the name entries not to propagate outside your network.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448607.aspx